# Custom file in Grub 2

Tags: bootloader, grub2

I have a image file which needs to boot along with my Ubuntu. When I open /etc/grub.d/10_linux for example, I see a lot of code written there.

What is the typical format for writing a custom file there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to edit **40_custom** file, and leave untouched 10_linux. You can find here specifications:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Creating_the_Custom_Menu